# Detox - Struggling to "build the Detox version of the binary, and run the tests" on a basic iOS RN app

Tags: javascript, react-native, detox

Cheers for your help. I'm super new to Detox, React Native, Macs, Xcode and posting on StackOverflow (new job), apologies if I'm missing details.

I'm following the guides from:
https://reactnative.dev

I've ran

npx react-native init MyTestApp

And have a working iOS app, in that I can start the bundler and interact with the demo app. I loosely get what is going on.

I then started following the guide here:

https://reactnativetesting.io/e2e/setup.html#installing-detox

I get to the section:

$ detox build -c ios

$ detox test -c ios

And for the life of me I can't get the detox build -c ios command to work, the output is as follows:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

warning: no rule to process file '/*****/*********/*****************/JamesReactNativeTest/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/benchmarks/CMakeLists.txt' of type 'text' for architecture 'arm64' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')
warning: no rule to process file '/*****/*********/*****************/JamesReactNativeTest/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/benchmarks/README.md' of type 'net.daringfireball.markdown' for architecture 'arm64' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')
warning: no rule to process file '/*****/*********/*****************/JamesReactNativeTest/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/README.md' of type 'net.daringfireball.markdown' for architecture 'arm64' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')
warning: no rule to process file '/*****/*********/*****************/JamesReactNativeTest/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/benchmarks/CMakeLists.txt' of type 'text' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')
warning: no rule to process file '/*****/*********/*****************/JamesReactNativeTest/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/benchmarks/README.md' of type 'net.daringfireball.markdown' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')
warning: no rule to process file '/*****/*********/*****************/JamesReactNativeTest/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/README.md' of type 'net.daringfireball.markdown' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the JamesReactNativeTest editor. (in target 'JamesReactNativeTest' from project 'JamesReactNativeTest')
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        Ld /*****/*********/*****************/JamesReactNativeTest/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/JamesReactNativeTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/JamesReactNativeTest.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Binary/JamesReactNativeTest normal arm64
(1 failure)
```

What's super confusing to me is my .detoxrc.json seems to have the right binary path because when I run that command via the terminal it works, I (probably wrongly) assume Detox is amending this command to make it fail? I read that your package.json is read by detox build but the command there for iOS works too.

I'm doing something super silly but I've got myself into a spin and can't see the answer. Apologies if a similar question exists already, I couldn't tie anything to my problem. Cheers again for any help you can offer.

detoxrc.json

```
{
  "testRunner": "jest",
  "runnerConfig": "e2e/config.json",
  "configurations": {
    "ios": {
      "type": "ios.simulator",
      "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JamesReactNativeTest.app",
      "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/JamesReactNativeTest.xcworkspace -scheme JamesReactNativeTest -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
      "device": {
        "type": "iPhone 11"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "type": "android.emulator",
      "binaryPath": "SPECIFY_PATH_TO_YOUR_APP_BINARY",
      "device": {
        "avdName": "Pixel_2_API_29"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "JamesReactNativeTest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.4",
    "react-native-macos": "^0.63.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "detox": "^18.2.2",
    "eslint": "^7.17.0",
    "eslint-plugin-detox": "^1.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-circus": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Had to add "-UseModernBuildSystem=YES -arch x86_64" to the build step to resolve.

Comment: Man you just saved me from a deep deep hole that i have been in for days now. Thank you! This helped me get my detox build running on M1.